# Объясните откуда взяли при вызове конструктора menu?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Menu(elem){
  this.save = function(){
    alert('save');
  },
  this.load = function(){
    alert('load')
  }, 
  this.search = function(){
    alert('search');
  }

  var self = this;

elem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var action = target.getAttribute('data-action');
  if(action){
    self[action]();
  }
});
}

new Menu(menu);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
  <button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
  <button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>
```

В целом код понятен только проблема возникла здесь new Menu(menu); откуда взяли menu ?

Comment: откуда то еще, здесь ведь не весь код представлен

Comment: @ThisMan Да в общем-то весь, сниппет-то работает.

Comment: @Yaant ммм, понятно. Работает он потому что браузер по умолчанию для каждого элемента с `id` старается создать переменную, поэтому у нас в окружении уже есть переменная `menu`, которая ссылается на элемент с `id=menu`, но как по мне лучше явно определять все переменные

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо я тоже вспомнил после вашего комментария что из-за этого придумали document.getElementById

Comment: @ThisMan что Вы написали существует по историческим причинам, надо использовать document.getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в данном случае `menu` - это то же самое, что `window.menu`, что в свою очередь, то же самое, что `document.getElementById('menu')`.

Маленькая иллюстрация:

```js
let e1 = window.asdfgh;
let e2 = document.getElementById('asdfgh');
let e3 = asdfgh;
console.log(e1 === e2);
console.log(e2 === e3);
```

```html
<div id="asdfgh">some text</div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам после комментария ThisMan  я вспомнил ... вопрос закрыт